# JDOM, umaluts and UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, jdom

I have issue with using utf-8 with JDOM parser. My code won't write encoded in utf-8.
Here's code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class Jdom2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {

    String textValue = null;
    try {
        SAXBuilder sax = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = sax.build("path/to/file.xml");

        Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
        Element application = rootNode.getChild("application");
        Element de_DE = application.getChild("de_DE");
        textValue = de_DE.getText();
        System.out.println(textValue);
        application.getChild("de_DE").setText(textValue);

        Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
        format.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(format);
        xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("path/to/file.xml"));

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
}
```

So line System.out.println(textValue); prints text "Mit freundlichen Grüßen", which is exactly what is read from xml file, but when it writing down, I get "Mit freundlichen Gr����"

Here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applications>
  <application id="default">
    <de_DE>Mit freundlichen Grüßen</de_DE>
  </application>
</applications>
```

How will I achieve writing "Mit freundlichen Grüßen"  instead of "Mit freundlichen Gr����" ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is probably the issue:

```
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("path/to/file.xml"));
```

`FileWriter` always uses the platform default encoding. If that's not UTF-8, you've got problems.

I suggest you use a `FileOutputStream` instead, and let JDOM do the right thing. (Also, I strongly suspect you should keep a reference to the stream so you can close it in a finally block...)

Comment: Not going to add another answer because Jon's is comprehensive enough... but, the documentation or XMLOutputter has a warning section for output to Writer instances: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html ... but, I don't think that is enough... how can it be improved ????

Comment: Actually, I opened issue https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/102 to improve this documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would totally go for @Jon Skeet answer, but if the code is in the 3rd party library that you cannot modify there are two other options:

1. Run your JVM with additional environment variable specifying file.encoding:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 … Jdom2
```

2. You can try to modify the `Charset.defaultCharset` which stores encoding used by `FileWritter`. Keep in mind that it's a very hacky solution that might break at some point and I would avoid it at all:

```
  Field field = null;
  for (Field f : Charset.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (f.getName().equals("defaultCharset")) {
      field = f;
    }
  }
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
  modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
  modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

  field.set(null, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

One last remark. Both solution might introduce side effects in other parts of your application because you are changing default encoding that might be used by some libraries.